# Executing program through Terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, python

I have Sage (math program) and I want to execute it through terminal.

I know I can go to the directory and execute it with -

```
open Sage.app
```

But would I really want to do is simply type sage in terminal and have it run. I believe this is a fairly simple task, but I just don't have any idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need an **alias**. Typing `alias sage='open /PATH/TO/Sage.app'` will create an alias which will do exactly what you want, run the program just by typing `sage`. The problem is that this will only last until you close that terminal window (bash). So, you need to create that alias each time you run a new bash. To do so, just:

1. Create or modify a text file called `.bash_profile` in your home directory.
2. Add `alias sage='open /PATH/TO/Sage.app'` on it
3. Save the file
4. Load the file once by typing `. ~/.bash_profile`

Remember that it will be case sensitive, so if you type `Sage` (instead of `sage`) it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a shell script named `sage` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
open /Applications/Sage.app
```

I suggest creating a `bin` directory in your home folder, and storing any scripts you create there. Save the script there with the name `sage`, then execute `chmod u+x sage` to give your user permission to execute the script.

Now, the last step is to tell bash that it should include any scripts found in `~/bin` in your path. To do this edit `~/.bash_profile`. You can do `nano ~/.bash_profile` or use any text editor you like. Add this to the file:

```
# Prepend ~/bin to the PATH variable
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Save and close `.bash_profile`, restart bash, and you should be able launch Sage.app by typing `sage`.

**EDIT:** An alias, like the other answer said, is probably a cleaner approach (1 less file to keep track of) if you don't need the logic of a script and just want to launch the app.

I've gotten used to doing it this way as most often I find myself passing a lot of parameters that don't change to an executable, but 1 or 2 that might. So I write the script to accept just those parameters and insert them in the right places when calling the executable. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Please try to avoid recommending the creation of new folders within the user's home directory, many people might want to keep a clean sorted home folder, and would prefer other solutions, like just using /bin (for example)

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - creating a new folder under home is much cleaner than writing to /bin - If you use command line binarieies and scripts you need a directory that you can write to without affecting other users

Comment: /bin is a great place for scripts meant for all users or the system in general, but user-specific scripts should really reside somewhere within the home directory. Creating a ~/bin folder makes them much easier to manage and backup. Also, I think it's too much of an assumption to assume that the OP has privileges to write to /bin or /usr/bin.

Comment: at least make a hidden folder >_>